# Php function to clear cache for regions

Tags: 7, theming, caching

I made a custom module, in which I dynamically add regions. The thing is, I want to make just the region part of the cache to refresh after. So drupal_flush_all_caches(); isn't the solution, since this takes too long, as well as it sometimes crashes the site.

Could anyone tell me which function I need to specifically clear the region/blocks cache? I tried all logical functions from the drupal_flush_all_caches(); function. I also couldn't find the right call from cache_clear_all();.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`cache_clear_all`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!cache.inc/function/cache_clear_all/7). You want to set first argument `$cid` to `NULL`, as you want expire all your objects. Now you only need to figure second argument, `$bin`. For sure you have to clear `cache_page` bin. If it's not enough, look inside your database for `cache_%` tables (where `%` means any string, per SQL standard) to know what bins are available to you.

Last but not least, dynamic regions may be huge performance hit. Think twice if that's what you really need.

Comment: Any idea which cache table governs the regions? None of the cache names really give away anything about the possibility of having the regions cached inside. And it's not the page cache. Because I got about as far as you've told me already, just couldn't find out which cache contains the region information.

Comment: @SanderKoedood It's in the `cache_bootstrap` table with a cid of `system_list`